# IE8 Only printing page 1 of webpages

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Got a problem that seems to be fairly endemic with IE8 (searching on Google) but I can't find a solution anywhere.  I have a document that is moderately long and should print to 3 or 4 pages, but sometimes IE8 only prints the first page (it also lists it as page 1/1, in these cases).  If I pause the printer (so I can wee what's happening in the queue without wasting loads of paper), then hit p  several times (without refreshing the page, or doing anything else in between), sometimes it submits all the pages to print, sometimes only 1.  If I use the print preview function to print, it always seems to print all the pages ok.  I have seen one possible solution to this which is, unfortunately, useless to me - to force IE into IE7 compatibility mode - I am, in fact, doing the reverse for these pages and forcing it into IE8 mode (it's an internal company site, so this isn't an issue).
I've also updated my printer driver, plus this issue exhibits itself over XP, vista (and I think 7 has also done this) all with IE8.
Has anyone found any solutions to this?
Cheers
MH

Comment: Are you printing a webpage that you have created?  You might want to direct your question to ServerFault.com

Comment: Yes, this is a dynamic webpage that my app is outputting, but it is just text and CSS, and so shouldn't be anything odd.  As I mentioned, poking around on google seems to bring up a load of blog entries, threads, etc mentioning this problem, so it doesn't seem specific to ourselves by any means, but nowhere does anyone seem to list a solution, apart from the workarounds I mentioned.

Comment: I also posted the issue up here as it's something devs will probably have come across as a process of implementing apps, and this seems to be the best forum site out of the many I post on for actually getting a decent answer =8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug with no usable workaround, closing Q

Comment: Seems to be caused when content exceeds width of page.
Occurrences can be reduced by printing in landscape, you could even specify landscape in css if you know this happens on certain pages:
@Page { size:landscape}

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround for user**

A workaround for the user would be:

1. Open the print preview
2. Jump to last page of document
3. Print

As a side note: The behavior in our case was that IE was printing "Page 1 of x" on first page, with x being the right number of pages. But only the first page was printed.

**Workaround for html designer**

Set `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">`
in your page.

Comment: @Page { size:landscape} made it print correctly... some times.
Your solution to emulate IE7 worked perfectly, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We've had the same problem. Compatibility View did work but changed the formating so we were unable to print on our specified paper (It had our University Logo in the top right). Removing all Add-Ons in IE8 worked temporarily however the final and complete solution was to upgrade to IE9.

I know this is around 5 years late but I thought if anyone else comes across this issue they don't have to spend hours trying to find a solution.

Oli